# Invoke-Command with Scriptblock in Filepath - no arguments

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2016

I'm working on a PowerShell script to override the out-of-office text on Exchange 2016.

I am doing this from a remote server who runs all tasks.

This is what I am calling:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -FilePath $filepath
```

This ps1 gets called with a parameter `-FilePath` and it works, it works for a simpler file.
Now to the file which gets put into filepath:

```
Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration |
    where {$_.AutoReplyState -eq "Disabled"} |
    Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -AutoReplyState Disabled -InternalMessage "ExampleTextIrrelevant"
```

So, I get all the mailboxes and then the configuration, only the disabled one and set the new text.

It works on the ExchangeServer.

Now I get the following error that he doesn't like the variable `$_.` in my `where` clause and also the scriptblock in the `where` clause he doesn't like.

I also tried to replace `where` with `Where-Object` etc. but it doesn't work.

Error messages (in German):

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:57  
+ ... ReplyConfiguration | where {$_.AutoReplyState -eq "Disabled"} | Set-M ...  
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
Skriptblockliterale sind im eingeschränkten Sprachmodus oder in einem
"Data"-Abschnitt nicht zulässig.  

In Zeile:1 Zeichen:58  
+ ...  Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration | where {$_.AutoReplyState -eq "Di ...  
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
Eigenschaftsverweise sind im eingeschränkten Sprachmodus oder in einem
"Data"-Abschnitt nicht zulässig.  

In Zeile:1 Zeichen:58  
+ Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration | where {$_.AutoReply ...  
+                                                          ~~  
Es wird auf eine Variable verwiesen, auf die im eingeschränkten Sprachmodus  
oder in einem Data-Abschnitt nicht verwiesen werden darf. Zu den Variablen,
auf die verwiesen werden darf, gehören folgende: $PSCulture, $PSUICulture,  
$true, $false, $null.  
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockNotSupportedInDataSection  
+ PSComputerName        : sv-exchange
```

Creation of `$Session`:

```
$User = "domain\user"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PasWorD" -AsPlainText -Force   
$UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord 

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ExchangeServer/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  It sounds like you aren't getting objects passed through your pipeline.

Comment: Well it works locally but not remote. The errors are : no Scriptblock and no Variable (§_) is possible...

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post the exact error message - that way anyone willing to help you won't have to guess.

Comment: Specifies a local script that this cmdlet runs on one or more remote computers. Enter the path and file name of
the script, or pipe a script path to Invoke-Command . The script must reside on the local computer or in a
directory that the local computer can access. Use ArgumentList to specify the values of parameters in the script.

When you use this parameter, Windows PowerShell converts the contents of the specified script file to a script
block, transmits the script block to the remote computer, and runs it on the remote computer.

Comment: updated with error information

Comment: Can you show the code that establishes the `$session` to the remote computer? What happens if you `enter-pssession $session` and try the series of commands interactively? Do `Get-Mailbox` and `Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` function as expected in the session?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/11/02/powershell-constrained-language-mode/

Comment: updated above.
If i use enter-psession i get the same error. i even get error for
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode

how do i check for a restricted mode?

Comment: So if i get it right...
I need to create a custom PowerShell endpoint and where i have FullLanguage?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

On the IIS on the Exchange Server, edit the web.config of the Powershell. There you can edit the language to FullLanguage.